# creating a pthread in c using that to wait for create thread to finish execution

Tags: c, multithreading, compilation

the following code, I create a pthread, then I  Have the main thread wait for the created thread to finish execution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * createThread(void * u){
  printf("Tread has been created");
}

int main(){
  //pthread_t tid;
  //pthread_create(&tid,NULL,&createThread,NULL);
  //printf("Main thread");

  //pthread_join(tid,NULL);

  pthread_t tid[2];
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,&createThread,NULL);
  }
  int j;
  for(j = 0; j < 2; i++){
    pthread_join(tid[j],NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

when I run this by suing `gcc 1_4.c -lpthread` then `./a.out` I have to wait for a long time before I can see an answer in my terminal!

what am I doing wrong or I cant see the problem with my for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In following loop you are incrementing `i` instead of `j`:

```
   for(j = 0; j < 2; i++){
    pthread_join(tid[j],NULL);
}
```

Change it to following and it will work fine:

```
   for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    pthread_join(tid[j],NULL);
}
```

Comment: i fixed that already.